# Verificar valores duplicados no array

Tags: php, array

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho o seguinte array:

`$array = array(10, 30, 10, 40, 40);`

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma simples de exibir a mensagem: "existem valores duplicados" ou "não existem valores duplicados".

A função `array_count_values()` poderia manipular esse array juntamente com o `foreach()` comparando resultado a resultado até encontrar uma quantidade maior do que 1. No entanto, gostaria de fugir dessa análise, pois só necessito saber se ocorrem valores duplicados e não quais são esses valores. Alguém teria outra idéia?

Comment: Você quer saber se existem valors duplicados no aray ou qur saber quais os valores duplicados? Para o rimeiro cenário a soluçao do @bfavaretto é perfeira, já para o segundo cenário o Idea reamente seia utiizar `array_count_values()` com um `foreach()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma maneira prática (mas não sei opinar sobre a performance) é filtrar as duplicatas para outra array, e comparar os tamanhos:

```
$array = array(10, 30, 10, 40, 40);
$copia = array_unique($array);
if(count($copia) != count($array)) {
    echo "existem valores duplicados";
} else {
    echo "não existem valores duplicados";
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://ideone.com/eg3Qgk)</sup>

Comment: A preocupação é justamente a performance. Já havia pensado em comparar o tamanho de dois arrays. Acho que a sua solução deve ser a mais simples mesmo.

Comment: Para uma análise simples, tanto essa solução é melhor quanto possui melhor performance, para uma análise mais detalhada realmente seria interessante utilizar o `array_count_values()`

Comment: Solução perfeita. Obrigado.

Comment: Excelente dica, acabei aproveitando em meu projeto hoje.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar uma forma usando a função nativa do php [array_diff_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
<?php
    
    //array
    $arr = array(10, 30, 80, 40, 40);

    //function
    function checkDuplicateElementArray(array $arr){
        $toCompare = array_unique($arr);
        return array_diff_assoc($arr, $toCompare);
    }

    //use
    if(checkDuplicateElementArray($arr)){
        echo "Existem valores duplicados";
    }else{
        echo "Não existem valores duplicados";
    }
```