# Obter valores duplicados do Vetor

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de obter somente os valores que estão duplicados no array

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$cdCursos = array(1, 2,3,4,5,3 );           
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $cdCursos );
echo "</pre>";
$withoutDup  = array_unique($cdCursos);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $withoutDup );
echo "</pre>";
$duplicates  = array_diff($cdCursos, $withoutDup);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $duplicates );
echo "</pre>";
```

O valores estão retornando assim, respectivamente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    1 => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 3
)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    1 => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

`</pre><pre>Array
(

)`

Tentei [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13345/54152) resposta, mas não deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(1, 2,3,4,5,3);

$uarr = array_unique($arr); 

print_r($uarr); //Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 ) 

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

var_dump(array_diff($arr, array_diff($uarr, array_diff_assoc($arr, $uarr)))); //array(2) { [2]=> int(3) [5]=> int(3) } 

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$unicos=(array_diff($arr, array_diff($uarr, array_diff_assoc($arr, $uarr))));

print_r($unicos); //Array ( [2] => 3 [5] => 3 )
```

[**no ideone**](https://ideone.com/Lo54hS)

[**no sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa9d99c29c61e477ddea7b3e5ebc6527174739b0)

Comment: Boa, garoto! Exatamente o que eu queria. Muito obrigao

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função `array_diff_key` ao invés da `array_diff` para este caso.

```
print_r(array_diff_key($cdCursos, array_unique($cdCursos)));
```